# How do I set user background for lightDM login screen?

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, desktop-background

I am quite lost on how to set user-specific background.
There does not seem to be many resources on this matter.

Setting background from `gnome-control-center` does not work.

`org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background` is set to `true`.

How do I set the user background for the lightdm login? Do I need to install another app to change backgrounds? Does `feh` affect such background choices?

(How could I get answers on these questions? Do I have to specify something? Anyone?)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the Greeter you are using. For instance. If you are using gtk-greeter you can use the main config:

Just look for `background` option in the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` file and set the filepath of your desired background image.

You can get more info here: https://github.com/canonical/lightdm

Comment: The problem is, I want to set the user-specific background, not a global one. I do not want to dictate the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. The greeter background is shown before you choose a user. So... How can be customised for the user if you haven't pick up one already. Do you wan't a dynamic background ? One that change depending on the selected user ?

Comment: What is a user background, then? I saw it in the e.g. lightdm slick greeter settings.